# get_attribute("title) returns empty string

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=graphic+card&page='

for i in range(1,2):
      driver.get(url + str(i))
      products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-container")
      
      for product in product:
                  brand = product.find_elements_by_class_name("item-brand")[0].get_attribute("title")
                  print(brand)
driver.quit()
```

I am trying to **scrape** data about graphics cards from newegg.com, however when i try to print the brand name of a product using get_attribute("title") , it returns an empty string. I have attached my code above.

Comment: Please add the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag with `class` `item-brand` does not contain `title` attribute. Try something like this.

```
url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=graphic+card&page='

for i in range(1, 2):
    driver.get(url + str(i))
    print(f"In Url {url+str(i)}")
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-container")

    for product in products:
        brand = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='item-brand']/img").get_attribute("title") # get "title" from each product. A "." before the xpath because we are finding an element within in an element.
        print(brand)
driver.quit()
```

```
In Url https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=graphic+card&page=1
GIGABYTE
MSI
Corn Electronics
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to be noted down.

1. Your loop is wrong, see this `for product in product:`
2. Use `explicit waits.`
3. Make sure `elements` are in `Selenium view port.`
4. Maximize the screen size.
5. for `fetching title`, it's better to target `a tag`
6. Below code `fetches` `title` as well as `product name`, in case you do not wish to `fetch product name`, comment the code.
7. Also, below code usages `xpath` for better traversing in `HTML DOM.`

**Code :-**

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=graphic+card&page='

for i in range(1, 2):
    driver.get(url + str(i))
    products = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-container']")))

    for product in products:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", product)
        product_name = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//descendant::a[@class='item-title']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
        brand = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//descendant::a[@class='item-rating']").get_attribute('title')
        print(product_name, brand)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
GIGABYTE Radeon RX 6700 XT GAMING OC 12G Graphics Card, WINDFORCE 3X Cooling System, 12GB 192-bit GDDR6, GV-R67XTGAMING OC-12GD Video Card Rating + 4
MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Card GTX 1050 Ti 4GT OC Rating + 4
CORN GTX 650 Ti 128-Bit 1GB GDDR5 Graphic Card DirectX11 Video Card GPU PCI Express 3.0 DVI/VGA/HDMI Rating + 4
AMD RX460 128-Bit 4GB GDDR5 Graphic Card DirectX12 Video Card GPU PCI Express 3.0 DP/DVI-D/HDMI, Play for LOL, DOTA, COD, War Thunder, Apex, etc Rating + 3
GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 OC 6G Graphics Card, 2 x WINDFORCE Fans, 6GB 192-Bit GDDR5, GV-N1660OC-6GD Video Card Rating + 4
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i7 11700F - GeForce RTX 3060 Ti - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i5 10600K - GeForce RTX 3070 Ti 8GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i5 10400F - GeForce RTX 3060 Ti - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700F - EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA CLC 240MM AIO Rating + 4
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i5 10400F - GeForce RTX 3060 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 512GB SSD Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700KF - EVGA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti XC3 Ultra Gaming - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel 670P M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO Rating + 4
ABS Challenger Gaming PC - Ryzen 5 3600 - GeForce GTX 1660 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 512GB SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700K - GeForce RTX 3070 Ti 8GB - 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA CLC 280MM RGB AIO - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 7 3700X - GeForce RTX 3070 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 7 5800X - EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 XC3 Ultra Gaming 8GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - RGB CPU Cooler Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i9 10900KF - GeForce RTX 3090 - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB  DDR4 3200 MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700KF - GeForce RTX 3080 - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel 670P M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO Liquid Cooling Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700KF - GeForce RTX 3070 8GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700KF - GeForce RTX 3080 - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD - RGB AIO 240MM Cooler Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i9 11900K - ASUS ROG STRIX GeForce RTX 3090 O24GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3200MHz - 2TB Intel 670P M.2 NVMe - Corsair H115i RGB Platinum 280MM - Windows 10 Pro Rating + 4
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i5 10400F - GeForce RTX 2060 - 16GB DDR4 - 512GB SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 7 3700X - GeForce RTX 3070 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - AMD R9 5950X - EVGA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3200MHz - 2TB M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 4
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i5 10400F - ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 3060 12GB - G.Skill Ripjaw V 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 512GB SSD Rating + 5
ABS Legend Gaming PC - AMD R9 5900X - GeForce RTX 3080 Ti - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Gigabyte AORUS Gen4 M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 5
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i9 11900K - ASUS ROG STRIX GeForce RTX 3080 Ti - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB AORUS GEN4 M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA CLC 280MM RGB AIO - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 5
ABS Master Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700F - GeForce RTX 3060 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA XR1 Capture Device Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 5 5600X - EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming 8GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 5 5600X - Radeon RX 6700 XT - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - RGB CPU Cooler Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - AMD R7 5800X - GeForce RTX 3080 Ti 12GB - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel 660PM.2 NVMe SSD - RGB CPU Cooler Rating + 4
ABS Challenger Gaming PC - Ryzen 5 3600 - GeForce GTX 1650 - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 512GB SSD Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700K - EVGA RTX 3080 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming - CORSAIR Vengeance RGB PRO 32GB DDR4 3600MHz - 1TB Intel 670P M.2 NVME - CORSAIR H115i RGB Platinum 280MM - Win 10 Pro Rating + 5
ABS ROG Gundam Limited Edition Gaming PC - Intel i9 11900K - STRIX Gundam GeForce RTX 3080 - G.Skill 32GB 3200MHz - 2TB Intel M.2 - STRIX Gundam 360MM AIO - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700F - EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming - 16GB DDR4 3000MHz - 1TB Intel 670P M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA CLC 120MM AIO Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i9 10850K - GeForce RTX 3090 - 32GB RGB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB Intel M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Intel i7 10700KF - GeForce RTX 3070 8GB - 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - EVGA CLC 280MM RGB AIO - Windows 10 Home 64-bit Rating + 4
ABS Gladiator Gaming PC - Ryzen 7 3700X - GeForce RTX 3080 - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16GB DDR4 3200MHz - 1TB M.2 NVMe SSD - 240MM RGB AIO Rating + 4
ABS Legend Gaming PC - Intel i9-11900K - GeForce RTX 3090 - G.Skill TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3200 MHz - 1TB M.2 Gigabyte AORUS Gen4 7000 SSD - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Rating + 4
```